# Microsoft Excel mail merge Word - Birthday date wrong

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, mail-merge

I have been searching for hours in that issue. In my Excel Spreadsheet there is a date (birthday) in Date Format. Of course in a mail merge that would definatly be translated into text format. Meaning the following would occure:

> 08.10.1953 becomes 19640

My workaround was to implement a date function in mail merges field function which looks as following:

> {MERGEFIELD F14@ "dd,MM,yyyy"}

Is there a chance to get the date displayed correctly in Words function field?

```
My Excel Version: 16.0.11929.20234, 64Bit (also known as 1908)
My Word Version: 16.0.11929.20234, 64Bit (also known as 1908)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you doing mail merge in MS Word using Excel spreadsheet as a data source? 

I just tried using an xlsx file, with "Birthday" column formatted as 'Date', as mail merge data source for a docx document, and the dates were mail merged as expected using the simple { MERGEFIELD Birthday } field.

Comment: Hi Borislav, thank you for your comment. My sourcefield is F13 and is formatted as "date". I tried with a new document :(

Comment: I tried again, this time with xlsx data source, with a column named F14 formatted as a date, and, in the MS Word Document, a field with the following code:
`{ MERGEFIELD Birthday \@ "dd,MM,yyyy" } `
And the result is as expected:
08,10,1953

Comment: Hi, please view my answer below...it is ridicolus but it is working with a few "rules"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer to this ridicolous question is simple:

1. You need to place the title "Geburtsdatum" or "Birtday Date" on top and not in the third row under other text
2. Source list must only contain dates, if no date, empty

Now everything is working as expected. Thanks for your help folks!

Answer (score 1):

The result is good, only the **format** of the cell is inappropriate.

Change the format of this cell to a **date** format.

---

*The explanation:*

Excel saves dates as *number of days from December 31, 1899* (so January 1, 1900 becomes `1`).

(If you *directly* enter the date into a cell, Excel is so wise that it *automatically* changes the format to a date format.)

---

*Test:*

Enter `08.10.1953` into an empty cell — you will see the right date.

Then delete all formats from this cell - and you will see the number `19640`.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. The format of the cell in Excel is "Date short", when I change the field in Excel to "Text" it becomes also 19640, which is unwanted. I want in Excel and in the Mail Merge Document the Date itself.